# How do I figure out if user selected an image or a video using Xamarin.MediaGallery?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, video, media, photo

I am coding a cross platform app and currently working on where users can choose images or videos up to 10 using `Xamarin.MediaGallery` NuGet Package. This line, `var results = await MediaGallery.PickAsync(10, MediaFileType.Image, MediaFileType.Video);`, let's me choose both Images and Videos up to 10 and the code below takes the images, convert each into a byte array, and add them to an empty byte list and send it to another page. What I can confirm is that when a user selects, let's say, 5 pictures from their gallery, each picture is successfully converted into a byte and sent it to another page where that page displays the selected pictures.

```
 private async void PickFromLibrary(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var results = await MediaGallery.PickAsync(10, MediaFileType.Image, MediaFileType.Video);

            try
            {
                if (results.Files == null)
                    return;
                List<byte[]> byteList = new List<byte[]>();
                foreach (var media in results.Files)
                {
                    photoPath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), "rotated_photo.jpg");
                    var selectedMedia = media.OpenReadAsync().Result;
                    using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
                    {
                        await selectedMedia.CopyToAsync(memoryStream);

                        // skipped code. Rotate the image by 90 degrees to the right

                        byte[] rotatedImageBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(photoPath);

                        byteList.Add(rotatedImageBytes);
                    }
                    File.Delete(photoPath);
                }
                await Navigation.PushAsync(new EditPostPage(userId, textId, byteList));
            }
            catch (OperationCanceledException)
            {
                await Navigation.PopAsync();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                await DisplayAlert("Error", $"Failed selecting medias: {ex.Message}", "OK");
            }

        }
```

With the code above, this is the XAML code in `EditPostPage` that shows the images in `CarouselView`. I didn't implement any other code like `MediaElement` to display a video yet.

```
<CarouselView x:Name="imageCarousel" IndicatorView="IndicatorView">
             <CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Image Source="{Binding}" Aspect="AspectFill" RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Width}"
                            RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Height}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
        </CarouselView>
```

And below is the back end code where it takes the byte list and convert it back to images.

```
public EditPostPage(int userId, int textId, List<byte[]> byteList)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.userId = userId;
            this.textId = textId;
            this.byteImage = byteList;

            Appearing += (sender, e) =>
            {
                imageCarousel.ItemsSource = byteImage.Select(bytes => ImageSource.FromStream(() => new MemoryStream(bytes)));
                if (byteImage.Count <= 1)
                {
                    imageCarousel.IsSwipeEnabled = false;
                }
            };
        }
```

What I am struggling is that now that the users can successfully select images and the `EditPostPage` shows the images, I want the users to be able to select videos and the videos show up on `EditPostPage`. I did use `var results = await MediaGallery.PickAsync(10, MediaFileType.Image, MediaFileType.Video);` so users can select videos. But there are two things that I can't figure out.

1. I don't know if the `PickFromLibrary` method will also turn the selected videos into a byte array and send it to `EditPostPage`.
2. How will I modify `EditPostPage` so if the user selected a video, it shows the video, if the user selected images, it shows the images. I want to implement a code where the code determines if the selected media is an image or a video and act accordingly. That is, if user selects an image, it displays the image, if user selects a video, it displays the video. Even though I read MediaGallery doc in GitHub I can't figure out how to distinguish whether the user selected an image or a video.
   https://github.com/dimonovdd/Xamarin.MediaGallery

I was considering put something like the following code where I implement `IsVisible` function and make it true or false depending on the media type. But How would I figure out if the media type the user selected is an image or a video?

```
<CarouselView x:Name="imageCarousel" IndicatorView="IndicatorView" IsVisible="{Binding IsImageCarouselVisible}">
             <CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Image Source="{Binding}" Aspect="AspectFill" RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Width}"
                            RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Height}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
        </CarouselView>
        <xyt:MediaElement x:Name="videoPlayer" IsVisible="{Binding IsVideoPlayerVisible}" RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Width}"
                        RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Height}" />
```

Comment: `IMediaFile` contains an `Extension`, `ContentType`, and `Type` fields that should all allow you to distinguish a video from an image.

Comment: what is the purpose of converting to a `byte[]` instead of just passing the `IMediaFile`?

Comment: @Jason I used `byte[]` since it offers a more straightforward and generic approach. There isn't really a specific reason why I chose `byte[]`. I've never used `IMediaFile` before and have no knowledge. Is there a website or a doc I can view? Thank you.

Comment: it is in the [code](https://github.com/dimonovdd/Xamarin.MediaGallery/blob/030678ff5bea468fe1a3e4d50951e814d1fb8585/MediaGallery/MediaFile/IMediaFile.shared.cs#L8) of the repo you linked to